# calculate time complexity of given function in C

Tags: c, time

I need to calculate the time complexity of the f3 function:
[image]

My problem is that I can't succeed on calculate how many time I can appley sqrt() function on n till its lower than 1: `n^0.5^k < 1`
I can assume that the time complexity of sqrt() is 1.
any ideas how can I get the k value out of `n^0.5^k < 1` ? if I succeed that, then I think value the sum of the series: `n/2, (n^0.5)/2, (n^0.5^2)/2,...` would be easier.

Comment: Please don't include coode as an image.

Comment: Just assume that a compiler exists that will convert the code into the equivalent of "`int f3(int n) { return pre_computed_table[n]; }`"' and state that (for the hypothetical compiler) the code is "O(1)". Beyond that; I'm not even sure you can guarantee that the code will ever complete - for specific inputs it may be "O(infinity)" (just thinking about the overflows that occur for a case like "`f3(INT_MAX)`" makes my brain hurt).

Comment: Actually, my brain doesn't hurt that much. It's relatively easy to see that, for`g3(INT_MAX)`, it will never exit the "`for(i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)`" loop (technically it's undefined behavior, but I'd still expect "loop forever").

Comment: @Brendam Why do you assume the compiler would make a precomputed table? That would be a really dumb compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show the lower and upper bound.

First we compute the cost of `g3`.

Take for example, `n = 2^16`.

How many iterations we make in the for loop?

```
i=2^0, i=2^1, i=2^2, i=2^3... < 2^16
```

More or less, that would be 16 steps. So the cost of g3 is `O(log(n))`.

Now lets try to compute `f3`. Since it's using `g3` inside the loop, it would go as follows:

```
log(n) + log(n^(1/2)) + log(n^(1/4)) + log(n^(1/8)) + ...
```

That's for sure greater than `log(n)`, so we could take `log(n)` as the lower bound.

Now, in order to compute the upper bound we have to think, how many iterations does the loop do?

Take again `2^16` as an example:

```
2^16, 2^16^(1/2), 2^16^(1/4), 2^16^(1/8), 2^16^(1/16),
```

That turns out to be:

```
2^16, 2^8, 2^4, 2^2, 2^1
```

And in the next iteration we would stop because `sqrt(2)` rounds to 1.

So in general, if `n=2^2^k`, we make k iterations. That's `log(log(n))`. That means we could say `log(n)*log(log(n))` as the upper bound.

There is probably a more adjusted solution but this should be pretty accurate.

Comment: thx for the detail solution, I was mistaking about the time complexity of g3, I know the solution is `log(n)`, still how can I have the same upper bound?

Comment: @David Take for example, `2^8 = 256`, how many iterations does the loop of `g3` do? Also take into account that I'm using base 2 logarithm, so `log(2^n) = n`.

Comment: i think i found somthing, using log rules:
`log(n) + log(n^(1/2)) + log(n^(1/4)) + log(n^(1/8)) + ...`
` = log(n*n^(1/2)*n^(1/4)*n^(1/8)*...) = log(n^(1+1/2+1/4+1/8+...));

Comment: now, `n^(1+1/2+1/4+1/8+...+k) < n^2` making that:
`log(n^(1+1/2+1/4+1/8+...+k) < log(n^2)`
and the upper bound is `O(log(n))`

Comment: That's awesome, you found a solution better than mine :)